# find current wallpaper path and show original image in finder

Tags: image, applescript, wallpaper, multiple-monitors

I do have the following two applescripts which are doing the same thing in different ways. The scripts are finding and displaying the path and the image name of the current wallpaper on OS X Yosemite 10.10.3 and then showing the original image in finder.

I am working in dual monitor mode, so I have to find the current wallpaper for the primary monitor and for the secondary monitor. In my scripts I address the different monitors either with "desktop 1" and "desktop 2" or with "preferences.picture_id=3" for the primary monitor or "preferences.picture_id=5" for the secondary monitor.

Both scripts are working in principle, but because of some reason both scripts are sometimes not working for both monitors (Primary and secondary) but just for one of them. Sometimes for primary but not secondary and sometimes visa versa.

If the scripts are not working they showing the error number 10010.

I searched the net for days and I tried all kind of different things bit I could not find the problem. I have to say I am not a applescripts specialist. Help would very much appreciated.

Kind Regards,

Peter

Here are the two scripts:

Script 1:

```
tell application "System Events"
    set posix_path to (pictures folder of desktop 2)
    set picPath to (POSIX file posix_path) as string
end tell
tell application "System Events"
    tell current desktop
        if picture rotation = 0 then
            tell application "System Events"
                set posix_path to (picture of desktop 2)
                set thePicture to (POSIX file posix_path) as string
            end tell
            tell application "Finder"
                reveal thePicture
                activate
            end tell
        else
            set thePictures to (do shell script "sqlite3 ~/Library/Application\\ Support/Dock/desktoppicture.db \"SELECT * FROM data\" | sed -n '$p'")
            set fullPath to picPath as string
            set rotationImage to fullPath & thePictures
            tell application "Finder"
                reveal rotationImage
                activate
            end tell
        end if
    end tell
    tell application "Finder"
        get selection
        repeat with moose in result
            if original item of moose exists then
                reveal original item of moose
            end if
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

Script 2:

```
tell application "System Events"
    set posix_path to (pictures folder of desktop 1)
    set picPath to (POSIX file posix_path) as string
end tell
set thePictures to (do shell script "sqlite3 ~/Library/Application\\ Support/Dock/desktoppicture.db \"SELECT data.value FROM preferences INNER JOIN data on preferences.key=16 and preferences.picture_id=3 and preferences.data_id=data.ROWID\"")
set fullPath to picPath as string
set rotationImage to fullPath & thePictures
tell application "Finder"
    reveal rotationImage
    activate
end tell
tell application "Finder"
    get selection
    repeat with moose in result
        if original item of moose exists then
            reveal original item of moose
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: So, you just want to reveal the location of the wallpapers for your various desktops?

Answer (score 1):

If what you're trying to do is show the current wallpapers for your desktops, you can simply use this code:

```
tell application "System Events"
    repeat with current_desktop in desktops
        set picPath to POSIX file (picture of current_desktop) as string
        tell application "Finder" to reveal picPath
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks for the script. When I run it on my iMac I get the following error message: (German User Interface)

error "POSIX file \"/Users/Peter/Pictures/Wallpaper/Movies/The_Book_Thief_2013_Movie_Wallpaper_5_xyfxl_2560x1440.jpg\" of application \"System Events\" kann nicht in Typ string umgewandelt werden." number -1700 from file "Macintosh HD:Users:Peter:Pictures:Wallpaper:Movies:The_Book_Thief_2013_Movie_Wallpaper_5_xyfxl_2560x1440.jpg" to string

Comment: Actually I found a solution: I have two running scripts which do what I wanted them to do and I would like to copy them in here but I am only allowed to copy 600 characters in here. How can I publish my scripts?